# Android Drawing a shape programatically on bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, curve

I want to draw a shape like:

[image]

I can use this shape to draw over canvas but I have to create this bitmap on runtime with black and what color. Is there any way to do this like using path or something else?

Comment: HTML5 canvas (JavaScript) or Java?

Comment: Its Java. I am working on android app.

Comment: You can draw it on canvas using combinations of Lines and Arcs.

Comment: What @Dharmendra said. Have a look at [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Graphics/Drawing_shapes) to get the basic idea.

Comment: Sorry buddy, it did not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this like using path or something else?

Yes, you could create it with a `Path`:

```
// the Paint for the path
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setAntiAlias(true);
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
// the path
Path pth = new Path();      
pth.moveTo(50, 200); // example values, modify with your own, or to improve the path
pth.lineTo(70, 140);
pth.quadTo(150, 115, 230, 140);
pth.lineTo(250, 200);
pth.quadTo(150, 165, 50, 200);
pth.close();
```

Make sure that the values you use for the path are in the `Bitmap`'s bounds so you can see the path.